# Python: Problems adding items to list in a class

Tags: python

I've got a class defined with a method to add items to it:

```
class ProdReg:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__PListe=[]
    def addProdukt(self,pItem): 
        self.__Pliste.append(pItem)
```

When I instantiate a ProdReg object and try to add an object to it with the following code i gent an error:

```
pr.addProdukt(b)
```

I get the following error:
AttributeError: `'ProdReg' object has no attribute '_ProdReg__Pliste'`

What's wrong? I'm not able to figure thisone out.

/Andy.l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in the `__init__` you wrote: `__PListe` and in the the `addProdukt` method, you wrote `__Pliste`. Python is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that.Been looking at the code "for ever" without catching that one.

Answer (score 3):

It's a typo in your code I think, or a misunderstand of how names work.  In Python names are case-sensitive.

You add the attribute as `PListe` then reference it as `Pliste`.  In one in the `L` is lower case and in the other it is upper case.